# Trading Assets via Smart Contracts

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

First of all, I am a beginner in this field.
Now, I want to develop a Dapp for real-estate assets trading, but to do that I need some blockchain accounts (addresses) that already contain these kinds of assets to begin my development. 
My question is: Are the ERC-20 tokens will be the right way to represent these kinds of assets?

Haim

Answer (score 2):

חיים חדד

Welcome to Ethereum and blockchain

You can have ERC-20 tokens for each asset as a token and you can track assets through tokens, I would suggest you use ERC-20 only if you deal with ether in your assets otherwise you can control assets

Comment: I am using ether .

Comment: Can I add the house details to the token? I need to save the address of the house, owner name, id, value and so on. I look at the erc-20 as a coin. Is it possible to create a token per each house with all the demands I already mentioned?

Comment: Yeah you can have each token (contract) embedded with house details and you can track it

Comment: Can you suggest other ways to do it (generally)?